# unable to crawl a website using scrappy but the same website can be requested and used using scrappy shell using same settings

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to crawl the website https://www.rightmove.co.uk/properties/105717104#/?channel=RES_NEW
but I get (410) error

INFO: Ignoring response <410 [https://www.rightmove.co.uk/properties/105717104>](https://www.rightmove.co.uk/properties/105717104%3E): HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

I am just trying to find the properties that have been sold using the notification on the page "This property has been removed by the agent."

I know the website has not blocked me because I am able to use the scrappy shell to get the data and also view(response) works fine too, I can directly go to the same URL using web browser so the 410 doesn't make sense I can also crawl pages from the same domain,
(ie) the pages without the notification "This property has been removed by the agent."

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem's the when a listing has been marked as removed by and agent on Rightmove then the website will return status code `410 Gone` (Which is quite weird). But to solve this, simply do something like this in your request:

```py
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url='https://www.rightmove.co.uk/properties/105717104#/?channel=RES_NEW',
        meta={
            'handle_httpstatus_list': [410],
        }
    )
```

**EDIT**

Explanation: Basically, Scrapy will only handle the status code from the response is in the range `200-299`, since `2XX` means that it was a successful response. In your case, you got a `4XX` status code which means that some error happened. By passing `handle_httpstatus_list = [410]` we tell Scrapy that we want it to also handle `410` responses and not only `200-299`.

Here is the docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#std-reqmeta-handle_httpstatus_list

Comment: Thank you soo much. It worked. I searched online and couldn't get a clear explanation, Could you tell me what 'handle_httpstatus_list': [410], is doing ? it could help others aswell

Comment: Of course, I've added an edit.